# Bad class file error when using Scala 2.8.x (2.8.0 and 2.8.1) in Javafx 1.x (1.2 and 1.3.1)

Tags: scala, javafx, javafx-1

When trying to import scala.Option in a javafx script, I get the following javafxc error:

```
cannot access scala.Option.$anonfun$orNull$1
bad class file: scala/Option$$anonfun$orNull$1.class(scala:Option$$anonfun$orNull$1.class)
undeclared type variable: A1
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
import scala.Option;
```

I am using Scala 2.8.1, Javafxc 1.3.1_b101, JVM 1.6.0_21-b06, OS Ubuntu 10.10. The same code was working in Scala 2.7.7 .

**Later edit:**
The same error is reported in case I import scala.immutable.Seq/List/Traversable/Iterable . I have tried the imports in a default **Netbeans 6.9.1** JavaFX project which has in the classpath only scala-library.jar.

Comment: Make sure the *entire* codebase is recompiled against the RC. Cached class files are a PITA. Also make sure there is no other `scala.Option` stable identifier being picked up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to import scala.Option into a default Netbeans 6.8 JavaFX project which has in the classpath only scala-library and I get the same error. I've noticed that the same error (it complains about a different class, but following the same name pattern) is reported  if I import scala.immutable.collection.Seq/List/Iterable .

Answer (score 1):

It reminded me first of [#4067](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4067), but this one looks quite different.

I would suggest that you try to reproduce the error with 2.8.1 or 2.9 trunk, maybe it is fixed?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have just tried it with Scala 2.8.1 and I still get an error, though the error is different. I have updated the question.